# WordPress: Loading another page/post inside the "the_content" filter creates an 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, elementor

I would like to modify a posts content with the "the_content" filter.
Inside this filter I would like to load another posts content.

This is my code:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_content_filter' );

function my_content_filter( $content ){

    if ( !is_singular( 'my-custom-post-type' ) ){
        return $content;
    }

    ob_start();

    echo '<p>SOME HTML BEFORE THE CONTENT</p>';

    echo $content;

    echo '<p>SOME HTML AFTER THE CONTENT</p>';

    $module = get_post( 12345 ); // load specific post
    echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $module->post_content );

    echo '<p>SOME MORE HTML</p>';

    $html = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    return $html;

}
```

Sadly this creates a 500 Internal Server Error.
I guess because I created an endless loop. Do you have any idea how to get the formatted content of another post inside the "the_content" filter?

Thanks :-)
Jan

**EDIT**

A bit more details: I created a custom post type called "sidebars" where I edit the content with a page builder. I would like to add this sidebars with PHP.

Comment: First, don’t call the same filter inside of itself, that leads to infinite recursion. Second, if your filter isn’t applicable, such as the singular check, **always** return what was provided as the first argument, unchanged. You have opted into an override as an absolute truth. If your code decides it doesn’t need to run, you need to say “never mind”, and the way to do that is to return what was provided.

Comment: There is probably a better way to solve your problem than this, however we’d need more details. Specifically, why can you just either change the original post once and for all, or just redirect the old to the new.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your reply! I created a custom post type called "sidebars" where I edit the content with a page builder. I would like to add this sidebar posts with PHP.

Comment: Can you just pull this content in at the template level instead?

Comment: I would prefer a solution that is not tied to the theme or templates. Luckily I use the page builder Elementor and was able to find a solution with it. Thanks for your ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

With the "Elementor" page builder you can do this:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_content_filter' );

function my_content_filter( $content ){

    if ( !is_singular( 'my-custom-post-type' ) ){
        return $content;
    }

    ob_start();

    echo '<p>SOME HTML BEFORE THE CONTENT</p>';

    echo $content;

    echo '<p>SOME HTML AFTER THE CONTENT</p>';

    $elementor = \Elementor\Plugin::instance();
    echo $elementor->frontend->get_builder_content( 12345 );

    echo '<p>SOME MORE HTML</p>';

    $html = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    return $html;

}
```